# How to validate forms?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem to validate forms I tried with many forms but I can't get the solution could you please help me because required does not work and also with

```
<div *ngIf="firstname.error?.required">First Name is required</div>
```

this is my code

```
<div class="md-form">
                  <input type="text" id="materialRegisterFormFirstName" class="form-control"  name="materialRegisterFormFirstName" [(ngModel)]="firstname">
                  <label for="materialRegisterFormFirstName">First name</label>
                  <div *ngIf="firstname.error?.required">First Name is required</div>
                </div>
```

and this is the error that receives when I try to use

```
<div *ngIf="firstname.error?.required">First Name is required</div> 

RegisterComponent.html:19 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (RegisterComponent.html:21)
    at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:36055)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:35067)
    at callViewAction (core.js:35433)
```

Comment: There are two ways of doing forms in Angualr, Reactive forms and Template driven forms.  https://angular.io/guide/form-validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using a **Template Driven Form** which mainly uses `NgModel`.

With that, you need to:

```
 <input type="text" 
        id="materialRegisterFormFirstName" 
        class="form-control"  
        name="firstname"              // It should have the same name as your ngModel
        [(ngModel)]="firstname"
        #firstname="ngModel">         // You need to add this input reference

 // You can then perform this line since the "firstname" refers to the #firstname="ngModel" from the input property:
 <div *ngIf="firstname.error?.required">First Name is required</div>
```